# Manipulate file input to post to Python's WebSSH server?

Tags: javascript, python

I'm trying to be able to automatically connect to SSH in the browser via just a URL. I've got https://github.com/huashengdun/webssh running, and I can pass a lot of it, except the private key.

The issue is, the private key is stored remotely.

I've thought about posting to the URL but I can't find a way in JavaScript or HTML to manipulate the input or set it to the binary stream of the file.

Is there any way I can set this up? They have options for using it via the browser but I have no idea what code that is and where it runs? Is this a JS package?

Comment: I believe you'll need to fetch the private key (through an AJAX request, perhaps) and pass it to the `webssh.connect` call.  That means anyone who can read your Javascript can fetch your private key, but that's always going to be the case for an open SSH service delivered through a browser.

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks for this. The `webssh.connect`, is this a JS library I can use? I'm trying to connect from a React.JS app.

Comment: Have you not browsed the source code of that repo?  `static/js` contains the Javascript code to make the AJAX requests.  Just go to the link you posted above -- the front page README even shows an in-browser Javascript example.

Comment: I understand this. The problem I'm facing is, how do I execute the `webssh.connect` command automatically, as I can only run it via the webssh server URL, and I'm trying to connect from a JS app on a different domain.